# Show the posts certain orders

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a question about showing certain orders from data. I have created colors table from the database. There are 256 row and the name colors. The database rows looks like his : https://prnt.sc/geyp48 and i want to show that like this screen https://prnt.sc/geypbr .

Now All colors have 14 different codes. Like for example red color have 14 different color type.

I want to show each of them in 14 order.

```
<div class="red">All in 14 different red color code</div>
<div class="blue">All in 14 different blue color code</div>
<div class="gren">All in 14 different green color code</div>
<!--All others will be come here-->
```

I know i can to it like this for first 14

```
$query = mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT id, colors, color_name FROM colors WHERE id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0,14") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
```

But if i use `ASC LIMIT 0,14` i should create many query about it for all other 14 color code.

My question is, how do I show in a different sequence every 14 div.

Comment: To handle this with your current table, I think you would need a seriously ugly set of `CASE` expressions in your `ORDER BY` clause.  If you really have this long term need, I would recommend creating a wavelength or frequency column for each color of visible light.  Then, you could easily sort using this.  Perhaps the hex code would already make this possible.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't `ORDER BY` id. That makes the order depend upon order of insertion, which is in my opinion very brittle. You could order by color code, assuming each one starts with the same "color category", but that again is very brittle.

What you should do is normalize. Add a new table, `color_category` where you add each color. Then via foreign key assign each row a color category. It can be a `VARCHAR()` column with the color category too, but that in the long run may bring you headaches (different color spellings, etc.). So try and normalize it with a new table. Then you can `JOIN` it to the original table to get the color categories for each row. Something like this:

[image: tables schema]

So, when you have that, you can `ORDER BY color_category_id` and in your code, while iterating, detect when the color_category changes and then start a new DIV or whatever you need to do.